# React Native - Sending FormDate to C# API

Tags: c#, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to send two pieces of information from my React Native app to my C# API.

I just need to send a UserId along with a picture. If I use form-data on PostMan the information is reaching the API successfully and everything is working perfectly. Sending the data via React Native is where I am running into problems.

It is not getting the user ID. I am sending a value of 2 but by the time I get it on the API it is 0.

React native code (snippet):
(Api is an instance of Axios)

```
        Api.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'

        var name = userId + '.jpg'
        let formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('userId', userId)
        formData.append('profilePicture', {
            uri:
                Platform.OS === 'android'
                    ? profilePicture.uri
                    : profilePicture.uri.replace('file://', ''),
            name: name,
            type: 'image/jpg',
        })

        const response = await Api.patch('/User/SaveProfilePictureUri', {
            formData,
        })
```

C# code (snippet):

```
        [HttpPatch]
        [Route("SaveProfilePictureUri")]
        public async Task<bool> SaveProfilePictureUri([FromForm(Name = "userId")] int userId, [FromForm(Name = "profilePicture")] IFormFile profilePicture)
        {
            Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Requestor", out var requester);
            _securityService.ValidRequester(requester);
            Request.Headers.TryGetValue("JwtToken", out var jwtToken);
            _securityService.CheckAuthentication(userId, jwtToken);

            return await _userService.SaveProfilePictureUri(userId, profilePicture);
        }
```

What other things can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out.

I needed to remove the curly braces from around formData in the API call. :facepalm:

From:

```
const response = await Api.patch('/User/SaveProfilePictureUri', {
            formData,
        })
```

To:

```
const response = await Api.patch('/User/SaveProfilePictureUri', formData)
```